How to create a specific grid area layout using html and css
I am currently struggling to get this specific grid layout in html and css. Is there anyone who can help me achieve this?

I have tried the following html and css:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 3px;
  grid-template-areas: "one two" "three four";
  grid-template-rows: 1fr .6fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: red;
}

.child {
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#one {
  grid-area: one;
  height: 947px;
}

#two {
  grid-area: two;
  height: 616px;
}

#three {
  grid-area: three;
  height: 616px;
}

#four {
  grid-area: four;
  height: 947px;
}
``
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="one" class="child">1</div>
  <div id="two" class="child">2</div>
  <div id="three" class="child">3</div>
  <div id="four" class="child">4</div>
</div>



The result is shown below:


If you think about three rows, then you can update your grid-area to grid-template-areas:         "one two"         "one four"         "three four"; and remove or update  the grid-template-rows rule
